# Django UserCreationForm not working

Tags: django

This is my registration form view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class RegistroUsuario(FormView):
    template_name = "perfiles/registro_usuario.html"
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("cliente:mi_perfil") 

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print("form_valid")
        return super(RegistroUsuario, self).form_valid(form)
```

It prints "form_valid". But it doesn't actually create a user. It redirects to the `success_url` but when I check which user is "logged in", it is an `AnonymousUser`. I don't understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the [FormView](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.8/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/) class the form_valid method doesn't save the form for you. You need to add it, like this:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.save()
    return super(RegistroUsuario, self).form_valid(form)
```

That behaviour is used by [CreateView](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.8/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/) and [UpdateView](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.8/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/).